# Powershell: How to properly count number of items in array of objects when there is only one object left in array

Tags: arrays, powershell, psobject

I have an array of objects with N properties each.
I perform a subset operation using `Where-Object` like this, for instance:

```
$mySubset = $myArrayOfObjects | Where-Object {($_.Property1 -eq 'ABC') -and ($_.Property2 -eq 'DEF')}
```

I then need to check how many objects I have in this array. I do it like this:

```
$mySubset.Count
```

When I have more than one object in the subset array, it shows number of objects. But when I have only one object left in `$mySubset` - it doesn't treat it as array with one element, and `$mySubset.Count` returns N - number of properties in each object. This is the problem.
How do I convince Powershell to treat `$mySubset` as an array with 1 item in it in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most PowerShell-idiomatic solution is to use `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), which ensures that a command's output is treated as an array even if only *one* object is returned:

```
$mySubset = @($myArrayOfObjects | ...)
```

To get the count directly: `@($myArrayOfObjects | ...).Count`

You can also use an `[array]` *type constraint* - in essence, a cast placed to the *left* of the target variable - which doesn't require modification of the RHS:

```
[array] $mySubset = $myArrayOfObjects | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is the way:

```
$mySubset = [PSObject[]]($myArrayOfObjects | Where-Object {($_.Property1 -eq 'ABC') -and ($_.Property2 -eq 'DEF')})
```

Or, as an one liner:

```
([PSObject[]]($myArrayOfObjects | Where-Object {($_.Property1 -eq 'ABC') -and ($_.Property2 -eq 'DEF')})).Count
```

Key point is to put parenthesis in right places, so, for instance

```
[PSObject[]]($myArrayOfObjects | Where-Object {($_.Property1 -eq 'ABC') -and ($_.Property2 -eq 'DEF')}).Count
```

would still show you N instead of "1" if number of object left is one.

Comment: Note that there's no good reason to use `[psobject]` in user code; `[object[]]` will do or - more simply - `[array]`. In fact, wrapping objects in `[psobject]` instances can have subtle, unwanted side effects - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this behavior is convenient, but not always....

Fortunately the workaround is simple:

```
$mySubset = @($myArrayOfObjects | Where-Object {($_.Property1 -eq 'ABC') -and ($_.Property2 -eq 'DEF')})
```

Just put the result inside the array construct: @()

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$mySubset=@()
$mySubset += $myArrayOfObjects | Where {$_.Property1 -eq 'ABC' -and $_.Property2 -eq 'DEF'}

$mySubset.Count
```

I create an empty array. I filter the `$myArrayOfObjects` for objects where Property1 and Property2 are "ABC" and "DEF" respectively, and I save that to $mySubset. Then I give you a count of from `$mySubset`.